# Audio interface only being recognised for a few minutes

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio

So I just bought the 'UR 28M' audio interface from Steinberg and I'm having some problems with it. It's disconnecting randomly during usage and 'malfunctioning', absolutely non-stop especially when I try to actually do something using it.

I've installed the latest drivers for it. I've set it up with my DAW, Bitwig Studio, and after about 1 minute or 2 minutes of usage it malfunctions and disconnects. It does not turn off it just disconnects. The hardware comes with a piece of software called dspMxFxUR28M which lets you see the values and turn some knobs, however, after my audio interface disconnects it just says 'not recognised' or 'cannot find interface' or something.

This is driving me up the wall so I hope you can help me. The reason it's making me so angry is because it breaks the audio driver I have for it in bitwig, so every time it malfunctions and disconnects I have to reinstall my DAW which is super annoying.

What can I do?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question far better directed to Steinberg, or perhaps Bitwig [as a quick google for 'bitwig studio asio' brings up several issues]?

Comment: Wild guess: bad USB cable, bad power cable, or malfunctioning power supply for the UR 28M. If the UR 28M tries to draw too much power from USB because it can't get power of its own, voltage drops and the electronics can't work properly, so it disconnects. So swap cables, try different USB ports, and measure power supply voltage if you have a multimeter.